# A set of libraries like ncurses in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, ncurses, terminfo

Supose you present the following `TUI` in the shell:

[image]

I need a set of libraries that can be used in the shell to do it. Being sure, `ncurses` has not been used, because it make a dependecy.

Question: How to build the widget/window or another `TUI` in the shell?

Comment: There's a `curses` module for `zsh`. Here's a quick demo: http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2019/msg00317.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, I feel like you might be asking one of two questions, so I will try to answer both.

1. What libraries can one use to create ncurses like interfaces for shell scripts?

   Actually, I would never have recommended ncurses directly for shell scripts anyway since it's really not meant to be used by shell languages. Instead, I would recommend [`dialog`](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/). Dialog is a shim library which sits between ncurses and the shell making its use much simpler.

   This would functionally give you two dependencies (one on `ncurses` and one on `dialog`) which you seem to be against for some reason.
2. Given that I don't want any external dependencies, how can I create my own ncurses-like TUI library?

   This is *way* outside the scope of *nix.SE. Creating a new TUI library is not going to be trivial (particularly if you're trying to create it in pure shell). There have been plenty of projects to attempt making new libraries to replace some of the use of ncurses (e.g., [`termbox`](https://github.com/nsf/termbox) is one of the more successful ones).

   If you intend to create your own library, you may want to look at the lower-level projects like ncurses and termbox and higher-level projects like dialog. Looking at their work might give you an idea of how to get started.

---

A final recommendation:

Dependencies on external projects, though they require some extra work (for integration and support), are *not* a bad thing. It means that you can focus only on the tool you want to make and leave the ground-work to those doing the lower infrastructure. Linux, in particular out of the *nix platforms, has a long history of dependency interaction.

If your goal is to learn how the lower-level stuff is done, great go for it. If instead you're trying to make a tool that would benefit from such low level work, just depend on an external tool. You'll be happier and so will be everyone that looks at your code.

Comment: Thanks, 1. i'm not going create a new lib. 2. I'm not going make a dependency such as ncurses. 3. i checked, dialog dpeend on libncursesw5 . 4. I guess if i want to use same lib, i want to use Terminfo , May be i extract tasksel , or mysql-server packages, because they have preconfigure script and dont' have any dependency. anyway thank you.

Comment: I really don't understand why you're against depending on ncurses…

Comment: ncurses one of stable library which exist is. But when terminfo is exist, Why make i a dependecy?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you want to do. Doing things by-hand in terminfo can be a bit of a nightmare (though the same might be said of ncurses).

Comment: Very likely terminfo on your system is a part of ncurses, in any case.

Comment: "though they require some extra work" they are well worth it, considering the payoff, or else they wouldn't have existed as a thing for so long in programming.

Answer (score 9):

```
#/bin/bash
      E='echo -e';e='echo -en';trap "R;exit" 2
    ESC=$( $e "\e")
   TPUT(){ $e "\e[${1};${2}H";}
  CLEAR(){ $e "\ec";}
  CIVIS(){ $e "\e[?25l";}
   DRAW(){ $e "\e%@\e(0";}
  WRITE(){ $e "\e(B";}
   MARK(){ $e "\e[7m";}
 UNMARK(){ $e "\e[27m";}
      R(){ CLEAR ;stty sane;$e "\ec\e[37;44m\e[J";};
   HEAD(){ DRAW
           for each in $(seq 1 13);do
           $E "   x                                          x"
           done
           WRITE;MARK;TPUT 1 5
           $E "BASH SELECTION MENU                       ";UNMARK;}
           i=0; CLEAR; CIVIS;NULL=/dev/null
   FOOT(){ MARK;TPUT 13 5
           printf "ENTER - SELECT,NEXT                       ";UNMARK;}
  ARROW(){ read -s -n3 key 2>/dev/null >&2
           if [[ $key = $ESC[A ]];then echo up;fi
           if [[ $key = $ESC[B ]];then echo dn;fi;}
     M0(){ TPUT  4 20; $e "Login info";}
     M1(){ TPUT  5 20; $e "Network";}
     M2(){ TPUT  6 20; $e "Disk";}
     M3(){ TPUT  7 20; $e "Routing";}
     M4(){ TPUT  8 20; $e "Time";}
     M5(){ TPUT  9 20; $e "ABOUT  ";}
     M6(){ TPUT 10 20; $e "EXIT   ";}
      LM=6
   MENU(){ for each in $(seq 0 $LM);do M${each};done;}
    POS(){ if [[ $cur == up ]];then ((i--));fi
           if [[ $cur == dn ]];then ((i++));fi
           if [[ $i -lt 0   ]];then i=$LM;fi
           if [[ $i -gt $LM ]];then i=0;fi;}
REFRESH(){ after=$((i+1)); before=$((i-1))
           if [[ $before -lt 0  ]];then before=$LM;fi
           if [[ $after -gt $LM ]];then after=0;fi
           if [[ $j -lt $i      ]];then UNMARK;M$before;else UNMARK;M$after;fi
           if [[ $after -eq 0 ]] || [ $before -eq $LM ];then
           UNMARK; M$before; M$after;fi;j=$i;UNMARK;M$before;M$after;}
   INIT(){ R;HEAD;FOOT;MENU;}
     SC(){ REFRESH;MARK;$S;$b;cur=`ARROW`;}
     ES(){ MARK;$e "ENTER = main menu ";$b;read;INIT;};INIT
  while [[ "$O" != " " ]]; do case $i in
        0) S=M0;SC;if [[ $cur == "" ]];then R;$e "\n$(w        )\n";ES;fi;;
        1) S=M1;SC;if [[ $cur == "" ]];then R;$e "\n$(ifconfig )\n";ES;fi;;
        2) S=M2;SC;if [[ $cur == "" ]];then R;$e "\n$(df -h    )\n";ES;fi;;
        3) S=M3;SC;if [[ $cur == "" ]];then R;$e "\n$(route -n )\n";ES;fi;;
        4) S=M4;SC;if [[ $cur == "" ]];then R;$e "\n$(date     )\n";ES;fi;;
        5) S=M5;SC;if [[ $cur == "" ]];then R;$e "\n$($e by oTo)\n";ES;fi;;
        6) S=M6;SC;if [[ $cur == "" ]];then R;exit 0;fi;;
 esac;POS;done
```